# How to compile ffmpeg on android with external library

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libx264

I would like to build ffmpeg using android ndk.
The basic clean build is work fine for me.
However, I would like to add librtmp,libfaac,libx264 into ffmpeg.
Then I add --enable-libXXXXX in build file,but it fail to do so.
So can anyone tell me how can I build those file for ffmpeg?
Where and what file should I put into the ffmpeg file?
Please give me a helping hand Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this git repository for a working compile with libx264: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

Take special note of the Project/jni/Android.mk

Also, note that performance will be pretty slow as your codecs are all in software.

Comment: So any suggestion can give me because i need to create an rtmp stream with h264 and aac from android to flash streaming server.

Comment: Also i found many way to compile ffmpeg and i use http://www.roman10.net/?p=389. So can i apply your suggestion